# How to select maximum 3 items per users in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I run a website where users can post items (e.g. pictures). The items are stored in a MySQL database.

I want to query for the last ten posted items BUT with the constraint of a maximum of 3 items can come from any single user.

What is the best way of doing it? My preferred solution is a constraint that is put on the SQL query requesting the last ten items. But ideas on how to set up the database design is very welcome.

Thanks in advance!

BR

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's pretty easy with a correlated sub-query:

```
SELECT `img`.`id` , `img`.`userid`
FROM `img`
WHERE 3 > (
SELECT count( * )
FROM `img` AS `img1`
WHERE `img`.`userid` = `img1`.`userid`
AND `img`.`id` > `img1`.`id` )
ORDER BY `img`.`id` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

The query assumes that larger `id` means added later

Correlated sub-queries are a powerful tool! :-)

Comment: Can you express in plain English how this works? I don't get it.

Comment: The subquery will eliminate any rows for which there are already three rows with the same userid and a lower image id. I think the greater than symbol in the subquery might be backwards though.

Comment: This is an example of SQL being more expressive than plain English :-)
Tom H. gave a good explanation; and yes, I'm sure the greater than symbol is correct

Comment: Ah. Now I understand. And the greater than is in fact correct. This is a lot better than mine. +1

Comment: @Niklas: For the fun of it - can you test my solution in regard to performance with your data? In terms of maintainability, Incidently's solution is the clear winner. But I have tested both on SQL Server, on a good amount of data, and mine feels a lot faster. YMMV, I'm interested what you find!

Comment: Wow. I'm totally favoriting this question, just so I can show people this query.

Comment: Won't this exclude all those who have more than 3 items rather than simply limit the number fetched from them to 3?

Answer (score 2):

This is difficult because MySQL does not support the LIMIT clause on sub-queries. If it did, this would be rather trivial... But alas, here is my naïve approach:

```
SELECT
  i.UserId,
  i.ImageId
FROM
  UserSuppliedImages i
WHERE
  /* second valid ImageId */
  ImageId = (
    SELECT MAX(ImageId)
    FROM UserSuppliedImages
    WHERE UserId = i.UserId
  )
  OR
  /* second valid ImageId */
  ImageId = (
    SELECT MAX(ImageId)
    FROM   UserSuppliedImages
    WHERE UserId = i.UserId
      AND ImageId < (
        SELECT MAX(ImageId)
        FROM UserSuppliedImages
        WHERE UserId = i.UserId
      )
    )
  /* you get the picture... 
     the more "per user" images you want, the more complex this will get */
LIMIT 10;
```

You did not comment on having a preferred result order, so this selects the latest images (assuming `ImageId` is an ascending auto-incrementing value).

For comparison, on SQL Server the same would look like this:

```
SELECT TOP 10
  img.ImageId,
  img.ImagePath,
  img.UserId
FROM
  UserSuppliedImages img
WHERE
  ImageId IN (
    SELECT TOP 3 ImageId
    FROM UserSuppliedImages 
    WHERE UserId = img.UserId
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

I would first select 10 distinct users, then selecting images from each of those users with a LIMIT 3, possibly by a union of all those and limit that to 10.

That would atleast narrow down the data you need to process to a fair amount.