# Selecting top 3 items per customer

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to select maximum 3 items per users in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271730/how-to-select-maximum-3-items-per-users-in-mysql)

I have an sql table with 3 columns:
CustomerNumber, Item, Count

There are about 125 items in this table; each row contains the customer number the item number and the number of times that customer has bought it.

I'd like to have a query with each customer and their top 3 items. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Did you search for top N per group? This is definitely a duplicate.

Comment: I did. For whatever reason, when I tried to adapt that query to what I was doing, it didn't work. Gave me every item for every customer.

Comment: What about select top 3 group by item

Answer (score 0):

```
set @i := 0;
set @cn = -1;
select CustomerNumber, Item, `Count`
from (
    select CustomerNumber, Item, `Count`,
        case when CustomerNumber != @cn then @i := 0 else @i := @i + 1 end as i,
        @cn := CustomerNumber
    from t
    order by CustomerNumber, `Count` desc
    ) ss
where i < 3
```